# ClassCastException in Vaadin scrollIntoView

Tags: java, vaadin

I try to use UI.getCurrent().scrollIntoView() to scroll to a label, but I get a casting exception. The method scrollintoView requires a com.vaadin.ui.Component, but my label is a com.vaadin.flow.component. What is the difference between a component in the com.vaadin.ui and com.vaadin.flow.component packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.vaadin.ui.Component` is Vaadin 7 & 8. `com.vaadin.flow.component.Component` is Vaadin 10 and newer.

Having both in the same project implies that you are using Multiplatform Runtime. In that context, you can use `ui.scrollIntoView(component)` for Vaadin 7/8 components whereas Vaadin <s>10+</s> 23.1+ components have that as a feature of the component itself as `component.scrollIntoView()`.

Edit: `component.scrollIntoView()` was introduced only in Vaadin 23.1. For older versions starting from Vaadin 10, you can use this workaround: `component.getElement().executeJs("var el = this; setTimeout(function() {el.scrollIntoView();}, 0);");`.

Comment: We use Vaadin 14.5.5 and no Multiplatform Runtime. So then it should be possible to use component.scrollIntoView(), but not ui.scrollIntoView(component).
Why is then not scrollIntoView() available for my com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label? The compiler just signals red. I don't find any code examples or references to scrollIntoView().

Comment: If you have something referencing `com.vaadin.ui.Component` on the classpath in a Vaadin 14 project without Multiplatform Runtime, then you probably have some issues with your classpath setup since that class only existed in Vaadin 8 and older.

Comment: `scrollIntoView` was introduced in Vaadin 23.1 so it's not available in the Vaadin version that you're using. As a workaround, you can use `component.getElement().executeJs("var el = this; setTimeout(function() {el.scrollIntoView();}, 0);");`